# Python Dictionary Loop doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary

I produced the following code to loop keys through a dictionary

```
favourite_languages = {
    'jen':'python',
    'sarah':'c',
    'edward':'ruby',
    'phil':'python'
    }

friends = ['sarah', 'phil']
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())

if name in friends:
    print(" Hi " + name.title() + ", I see your favourite language is " +
          favourite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

The output produced is

```
Jen
Sarah
Edward
Phil
 Hi Phil, I see your favourite language is Python!
```

I however, was expecting the following:

```
Jen
Sarah
 Hi Sarah, I see your favourite language is C!
Edward
Phil
 Hi Phil, I see your favourite language is Python!
```

Why does Sarah not come up in the output?

Comment: You need to move your if one indent level deeper.

Comment: Got it! @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ submit as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to move your `if` statement into the loop. In its current state, it is outside, and so will have access to only the last value that `name` took on.

Additionally, I recommend you store your `friends` as a set, for quick and efficient lookup.

```
In [193]: favourite_languages = {
     ...:     'jen':'python',
     ...:     'sarah':'c',
     ...:     'edward':'ruby',
     ...:     'phil':'python'
     ...:     }
     ...: 
     ...: friends = {'sarah', 'phil'}
     ...: for name in favourite_languages.keys():
     ...:     print(name.title())
     ...: 
     ...:     if name in friends:
     ...:         print(" Hi " + name.title() + ", I see your favourite language is " +
     ...:               favourite_languages[name].title() + "!") 
     ...:           
Phil
 Hi Phil, I see your favourite language is Python!
Jen
Edward
Sarah
 Hi Sarah, I see your favourite language is C!
```

Sets have constant time `(O(1))` lookup, while lists are linear `(O(n))`. It may not matter much for your particular use case, but sets really shine with large amounts of data.

As a further improvement, you don't need to call `dict.keys()`, since that creates a list of keys for the loop to iterate over, which is a little wasteful. The same thing may be achieved with:

```
for name in favourite_languages:
```

This is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @user3416724 Also note that `favourite_languages.keys()` can be replaced with `favourite_languages` to the same effect. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is that you just have to move you if condition inside loop.

```
favourite_languages = {
    'jen':'python',
    'sarah':'c',
    'edward':'ruby',
    'phil':'python'
    }

friends = ['sarah', 'phil']
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())

    if name in friends:
        print(" Hi " + name.title() + ", I see your favourite language is " +
              favourite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

Output:

```
Sarah
 Hi Sarah, I see your favourite language is C!
Edward
Jen
Phil
 Hi Phil, I see your favourite language is Python!
```

Comment: How does this differ from the other solutions posted?

Comment: I'm writing an answer, After post the answer I was come to know that you have already given the answer. I have tried my best to give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` variable in your if statement is set to the last value of `friends` after the loop, and the if statement is only executed once.

I think you want to indent the if statement (and print) so that it's executed in each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 2):

You're not looping over the `name` variable.

When your code reaches the `if name in friends`, the value stored in `name` is `phil`.

You could loop over the names again (which would produce a slightly different result), or add a indent to your code.

```
favourite_languages = {
'jen':'python',
'sarah':'c',
'edward':'ruby',
'phil':'python'
}

friends = ['sarah', 'phil']
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())

    if name in friends:
        print(" Hi " + name.title() + ", I see your favourite language is " +
              favourite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent your `if` block one level more.

```
...
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())
    if name in friends:
        print(" Hi " + name.title() + ", I see your favourite language is " +
              favourite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent `if name in friends:`

```
favourite_languages = {
    'jen':'python',
    'sarah':'c',
    'edward':'ruby',
    'phil':'python'
    }

friends = ['sarah', 'phil']
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title())

    if name in friends:
        print(" Hi " + name.title() + ", I see your favourite language is " +
          favourite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `if` statement into your `for` loop.